# Two roles in a company like a developer i.c.w. system administrator tasks

Tags: professionalism, compensation

I work for a small company. Less then 20 employee's. Occasionally, my employer wants me to do system administrator tasks because the company doesn't have a system administrator. When doing system administrator tasks I can't focus on development tasks. Nevertheless, I don't get more time for development projects.

Now I'm wondering if it's decent to ask for a raise or another compensation for doing 2 jobs at the same time.

Comment: Are you frequently working more than your scheduled hours?

Comment: @PhilipKendall No

Comment: OK, so your job description has changed slightly, but that's not really a reason for a raise, unless you're going to try and argue that your sysadmin tasks are significantly more complex/valuable to the company than your development tasks.

Comment: How complex can sysadmin be when there's only 20 staff, You need to reboot the router once in a while? I think you'd be pushing your luck here.

Comment: How long have you been there?  If you're a programmer in this market and it's been 6, 9 months or more, you should be demanding a big raise anyway (assuming you're pretty good and have built useful software).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I'm wondering if it's decent to ask for a raise or another
>   compensation for doing 2 jobs at the same time.

Certainly you can always ask for a raise.

But just having to chip in and handle an occasional sysadmin task doesn't make for a very compelling argument for a raise. If the company placed a lot of value on these tasks, they would hire someone to do them. So don't just emphasize the "because I'm doing two things" angle. In a small company, it's likely that lots of folks are doing two things.

Instead, when you ask for the raise focus on your overall value to the company, and the kind of value you will provide in the future. If the bulk of your work is excellent, then the additional task shows you are willing to go above and beyond - and that something employers value.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a small company and you'll often see the Engineering Manager doing basic I.T. support and the Managing Director helping out with packaging.

I've also worked at large multinational places where jobs were very firmly defined, but with small companies this rarely happens - there will be an "all hands to the pumps" moment on a regular basis, and with a small company this is probably a better thing than the alternative - that there's not enough additional work to justify expansion.

If you're interested in career progression, any experience will stand in good stead - when the company grows enough to have a department for development and systems administration, they'll know where to look for a supervisor.

By all means ask for a revised job description. You can ask for a pay review at the same time. And if the systems administration work means development work isn't getting done, you can use this as an argument for further recruitment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though your tone is cynical. What is the point of a revised job description?

Comment: @Julian - Aw. I liked the cynicsm, but I'll edit if you're not keen. The point of a revised job description is so you have formal recognition that your duties have changed. It gives a perfect introduction to a discussion about reviewing pay.

Comment: I saw no cynicism here, and I love cynicism!  :)

Comment: @Fattie You didn't see cynism because the answer was edited... speaking about dark comedy...